# How to change host name of Live Server VS Code?

Tags: javascript, liveserver

nice sirs. I wonder, is there any chance to change host name of Live Server to something custom? Like, not `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` this but this `http://denemedomain:5500`. I know may be it is a silly question but, i just want to change the host name. I am using vanilla jaavscript and i am begginer, so i just wondered if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that from the `hosts` file, you can specify the domain name mapped to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

If you are using `windows`, The host file path is

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Inside you need to append this.

```
127.0.0.1 denemedomain
```

So, whenever you write `http://denemedomain:5500` it will be mapped to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/`

Comment: Isn't it `hosts` instead of `host`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes for sure, thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing the server can do. This is something the client will need to configure in its system so that `denemedomain` resolves to the IP address `127.0.0.1`. This can be done e.g. in the DNS or in the client's [`hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).